# Port-forwarding Connection Not Working and No Install

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

I'm trying to run a command something like this here:
`kubectl -n some-namespace port-forward svc/some-namespace 2000:2000`

which produces an error like this:

```
error: The gcp auth plugin has been removed.
Please use the "gke-gcloud-auth-plugin" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.
See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke for further details
```

I've attempted:

- `gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` and checking `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version` returns
  `zsh: command not found: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`
- so then `sudo find / -name gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` which returns `/some/directory/google-cloud-sdk/bin` to the `PATH` and sourcing it but doesn't do much

Any ideas on what could be wrong or where to check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you should use the "gcloud" auth plugin. You can install the gcloud auth plugin:
*gcloud components install kubectl-gke-auth*
After that you may authenticate with your GCP account by running:
*gcloud auth login*
This will open a new window in your browser for you to log in. If you are working in a command-line environment just add the *--no-launch-*browser flag to the command to get a URL that you can open in a web browser on another machine.
After logging in, you can configure kubectl to use the credentials from your Google Cloud account with:
*gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone YOUR_ZONE --project YOUR_PROJECT_NAME YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME*
(You will need to replace YOUR_ZONE with the zone of your GKE, YOUR_PROJECT_NAME with the name of your project, and YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME with the name of your cluster.)
Once these steps are done, you should be able to run kubectl commands without seeing the error message about the gcp auth plugin.
Here is a document that can help and give you information about this.[1]
[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform